# ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have shape (9,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have the this dataset

```
step    pos_x   pos_y   vel_x   vel_y   ship_lander_angle   ship_lander_angular_vel leg_1_ground_contact    leg_2_ground_contact    action
0   0   -0.004053   0.937387    -0.410560   -0.215127   0.004703    0.092998    0.0 0.0 3
1   1   -0.008040   0.933774    -0.401600   -0.240878   0.007613    0.058204    0.0 0.0 3
2   2   -0.011951   0.929763    -0.392188   -0.267401   0.008632    0.020372    0.0 0.0 3
3   3   -0.015796   0.925359    -0.383742   -0.293582   0.007955    -0.013536   0.0 0.0 3
4   4   -0.019576   0.920563    -0.375744   -0.319748   0.005674    -0.045625   0.0 0.0 3
```

I split it as follows:

```
X = dataset[dataset.columns.difference(["action"])]
Y = dataset["action"]
    # Use a range scaling to scale all variables to between 0 and 1
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
cols = X.columns

X = pd.DataFrame(min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X), columns = cols) # Watch out for putting back in columns here
# Perfrom split to train, validation, test
x_train_plus_valid, x_test, y_train_plus_valid, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=0, test_size = 0.30, train_size = 0.7)
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(x_train_plus_valid, y_train_plus_valid, random_state=0, test_size = 0.199/0.7, train_size = 0.5/0.7)


# convert to numpy arrays
y_train_wide = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.asarray(y_train)) # convert the target classes to binary 
y_train_plus_valid_wide = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.asarray(y_train_plus_valid))
y_valid_wide = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.asarray(y_valid))
```

And i use the Neural Network to train my data

```
   model_mlp = Sequential()
    model_mlp.add(Dense(input_dim=9, units=32))
    model_mlp.add(Activation('relu'))
    model_mlp.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model_mlp.add(Dense(32))
    model_mlp.add(Activation('relu'))
    model_mlp.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model_mlp.add(Dense(4))
    model_mlp.add(Activation('softmax'))
    #model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

    model_mlp.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model_mlp.fit(np.asfarray(x_train), np.asfarray(y_train_wide), \
              epochs=20, batch_size=32, verbose=1, \
              validation_data=(np.asfarray(x_valid), np.asfarray(y_valid_wide)))
```

I almost got 93% accuracy. I save the model as follows

```
 filepath = "first_model.mod"
 model_mlp.save(filepath)
```

In another file where I need to load the model and calculate the reward I got above mention error

```
 if __name__=="__main__":
    # Load the Lunar Lander environment
    env = LunarLander()
    s = env.reset()

    # Load and initialise the contrll model
    ROWS = 64
    COLS = 64
    CHANNELS = 1
    model = keras.models.load_model("first_model.mod")

    # Run the game loop
    total_reward = 0
    steps = 0
    while True:

        # Get the model to make a prediction
        a = model.predict_classes(s)
        a = a[0]

        # Step on the game
        s, r, done, info = env.step(a)
        env.render()
        total_reward += r
        if steps % 20 == 0 or done:
            print(["{:+0.2f}".format(x) for x in s])
            print("step {} total_reward {:+0.2f}".format(steps, total_reward))
        steps += 1


        if done: break
```

Error is at following line : `a = model.predict_classes(s)`

Comment: Looks like env.reset() isn't returning what you expect it to return. Your Sequential Keras model is expecting the shape  of the input to be (9, the number of examples). env.reset() is returning an array with 1 as the starting dimension.

Comment: the value en.reset() returning is and array like this  [-0.0017684   0.93765326 -0.17912539 -0.1973398   0.00205582  0.04057457
  0.          0.        ]. How can I correct it?

Comment: You wrote 8 values there but there should be 9. You need to check what the shape returned by env.reset() is. If it's (1,9), just transpose. If it's (9,) (which I doubt by your error message) it should be env.reset()[:, np.newaxis]

Comment: shape return is s.shape= (8,)

Comment: Then the columns of the data with which you train your NN are mismatched with what env.reset() returns. My guess is that you included step as a column while training, but this isn't something returned by env.reset(). Please have a **long close look** at your code and what you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```py
X = dataset[dataset.columns.difference(["action"])]
```

- First of all, it includes `9` columns, instead of `8`, which makes the network incompatible with gym states returned from `env.step`. This causes the shape mismatch error.
- Next, `columns.difference` also shuffles the input columns (they become sorted by name). The columns thus become:

  ```py
  Index(['leg_1_ground_contact', 'leg_2_ground_contact', 'pos_x', 'pos_y',
     'ship_lander_angle', 'ship_lander_angular_vel', 'step', 'vel_x',
     'vel_y'],
    dtype='object')
  ```

The right way to split `X` and `y` is this:

```py
X = dataset.iloc[:,1:-1]
Y = dataset.iloc[:,-1]
```